# Using wordpress data in separate PHP application

Tags: php, database, wordpress, external

I have user dynamic web application, however it also contains some static pages(like Terms of Usage,...) and will contain some articles - for administration of this content I would like to use wordpress - so I wonder if there is a way how to include some wordpress's PHP which would only include the processed `the_content();` and needed WP objects? 

Or at least is there some way how to get raw html from data extracted from wordpress DB?

PS: Iframe solution just seems wrong to me... and would not work for me anywas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building your own php and don't want to use custom templates / post-types / etc... You can simply load WordPpress via

`<?php include 'path_to_wordpress/wp-load.php'; ?>`

And then you will have access to all the Wordpress Functions / Objects :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, this seems to do exactly what I need :)

Comment: and what do you think about the require('./wp/wp-blog-header.php'); ?

Comment: `wp-blog-header.php` loads `wp-load.php` and also templating. But in youre case I don't think you need it since you're building your custom php file. The was a discussion on Wordpress a long time ago if you wanna read more: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/integrating-site-and-blog-1

Comment: So if I want to use custom-programmed-shortcodes (basicaly in functions.php of the theme) - then I would have to include wp-blog-header?

Comment: Things like is_404(), is_seach(), is_front_page(), is_home(), is_tax(), etc... Won't work :) Your shortcodes are safe ;)

Comment: Wonderful, I thought that theme's functions.php are loaded by templating system :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you build the entire webpage using Wordpress? You can do pretty anything with it, especially if you use custom post types and custom fields.

Anyway, I found this forum threat that might contain information useful to you http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-wordpress-page-to-another-html-site?replies=5

Comment: WP has poor security and performance for this particular usage. So I would like to use it as static-page-administration only :)